# How to change the GET data with window.history.pushState

Tags: javascript

I have an url like this:

```
www.example.com/index.php
```

I need to change the url without reloading the page,so i have to use window.history.pushState as far as i've know,buti can't understand the syntax of this function,so i need some help with it.
If i want to add an id in url like this:

```
www.example.com/index.php?id=1
```

what will the syntax of window.history.pushState looks like ? Or if i want to change the id value ? 
(Im new to javascript so i have some troubles understanding it.)

Answer (score 2):

When you change the URL itself, the page has to reload, and even if you could prevent this, you should not do that. You could change the hash though, this would be accessed via `window.location.hash`, and changing this does not cause the browser to reload while you still can use it to have a different URL for sub pages and even move with the back and forward buttons.

Edit: In your case, you could do something like `window.location.hash = "id=1";`.

Comment: and if i want to change the id value ??

Comment: Then you write `window.location.hash = "id=2";`. If you only want to set the id, you could also omit the id= part and just store the id, this would probably be easier, but will result in a URL like `yoursite.html#2` instead of `yoursite.html#id=2`. You can also read the hash property, and you can set an event listener listening to hashchange so you get notified when the hash changes.

Comment: what i am looking for is to use the $_GET['id'] value . I have to change the url without reloading the page to create an id in url,but after that i have to use it in some other actions.I have test it,and $_GET['id'] is empty...

Comment: So you want to access the changes get parameter with your backend/PHP? You have to send an HTTP request in order to submit them, you could use AJAX with HTTPRequests, this will send a hidden request so you do not have to reload.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is: "You can't." It is not possible to edit/add/remove GET Data with window.history.pushstate - this is because GET information is sent to the server before the page is served, while any JavaScript interaction takes place after the page is served.